# How to call a python function from another Python file which I imported in my robot file?

Tags: python, python-import

My Folder Structure is as below

```
|
|--Folder1
|    |
|    |--helperAA.py
|  
|--Folder2
    |
    |---Folder3
          |
          |---Folder4
               |
               |---Folder5
                    |
                    |--Test.robot
                    |--helperBB.py
```

in the helperAA.py and helperBB.py files under Folder1 and Folder5 almost many functions are same lets say (func1, func2) but the other function is different (func3)

If I write func1 and func2 again in my Folder5/helperBB.py, it's going to be duplicate code. But I want to overcome this by importing helperAA.py in helperBB.py then access func1 from my Test.robot file

I came across an answer which tells that you need to import the functions one by one. Like this

```
from helperAA import func1,func2

function1 = func1()
```

This will require me to write a few lines of code which is going to be dependent on my helperAA.py file if it gets new functions

But my helperAA.py file might contain more than 10 functions which I cannot import 1 by 1. Instead, I want to import them all like this

```
from helperAA import *
```

And no other extra line to be added

I want to access the func1 from my Test.robot like below

```
**** Settings ****
Library    helperBB.py

**** Test Cases ****
Test case - 1
    func1
```

I don't want to touch any other directory other than Folder5. Is it possible?

Comment: "I came across an answer which tells that you need to import the functions one by one. Like this" - I very much doubt that. You **can** import individual functions like that, or you can also use the star-import. The code `function1 = func1()` is **calling** the function that was just imported and has nothing to do with the actual import. "Instead, I want to import them all like this" - then **do so**; I doubt that you *accidentally guessed* exactly what to type, but must have seen it in some kind of documentation instead. Please **try it**; there is no question of "possibility".

Comment: If you encountered a problem with `from helperAA import *`, it has **nothing to do with** the import syntax, and everything to with the rules that Python uses, to figure out the folders on disk that have your code in them. Please read the linked duplicate to understand this properly.

Comment: Also, the fact that you are using the Robot framework makes **no difference at all to any of this**.

Comment: Whatever that you mentioned will work without any problem when we consider python alone. But since I'm trying to access to a function which is insider an imported python file in another python file in a robot file. It sounds complex. The robot only looks for keywords in the python file which is imported in the robot file alone but not in the other python file which is imported in the imported python file

Comment: It really isn't as complicated as you expect. If your `helperBB` does an import like `from helperAA import *`, then that means that whatever `func1` is defined in `helperAA` is now *also* considered part of `helperBB`, *with the same name*, as viewed from outside (e.g. with the Robot framework). At least, as long as *it* works by importing the `helperBB`. Please just **try** the straightforward approach; if you run into a specific issue that way, then [edit] the question so that it has a proper [mre].